# How can I stream to Airplay and Bluetooth simultaneously?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, airplay, streaming

I have an iMac with airport express and I also have a logitech bluetooth speaker adapter.

Seemingly I cannot play through both at the same time.

I have even tried going to the MIDI settings and creating an 'aggregate' audio device but it just flips back after a few seconds of it being selected (to a working method)

EDIT: Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Comment: Did you try using the Multiple Output in MIDI ?

Comment: I can't see where that option is. From screenshots I've seen, that might only be in later versions

Comment: Sorry, I have the MIDI Version 3.0.5 on os 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

The app **Airfoil** allow multiple output synchronization (you can download a 10.6 version [here (Airfoil for Mac 3)](https://rogueamoeba.com/legacy/).